# Make a drop-down list of items in a field from a column of items in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to take a column of items in a Google Sheet and make a drop-down list that I can select from in a field in another part of the sheet.  Any way I can do this?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder

Comment: That gets me a data validation.  What I want is an actual drop-down list to select from with a blank entry at the end to allow me to enter a new value not on the list.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Try html with Htmlservice?

Comment: I've not used htmlservice and am not greatly fluent in html.  Can you give me an example of what I might try?

Comment: No. It'll take hours.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Spreadsheet Drop Down

```
function createSpreadsheetDropDown(sheetname,range,list) {
  var range=range||'A1:A5';
  var list=list||[1,2,3,4,5];
  var sheetname=sheetname||'Sheet13';
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  const rg=sh.getRange(range);
  var val=sh.getRange(range).getDataValidations();
  val.forEach(function(v,i){
    v=null;
  });
  const rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
  rg.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: OK, that looks great.  In my case, I wouldn't need to pass in values as I would be working with SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), with range set at 'M3:M49' and list set to SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(range).getValues().  Now, how do I "hook" this function into my field so that I can use it for data entry?

Comment: Also, let an old procedural (non-object-oriented) programmer ask a dumb question:  what does the code near the bottom  val.forEach(function(v,i) { v=null; });  do and why?

Comment: What's a field? What kind of data entry?\

Comment: M3:M49 has names of stores sorted in alphabetical order.  Only some (hopefully) of them will be populated, with the empty ones at the bottom.  I want a list of the non-empty ones, plus an empty one at the end, that can be used as a droip-down list for entry into C35-C45.The empty one will allow for free entry of data which will eventually be sorted back into M3:M49.

Comment: I don't think DataValidations will display empties.

Comment: It's easy to get the sorted list of values with the empty entry at the end,  What I don;t know how to do is link that list to a cell so that when the user enters the cell, the list is calculated and presented.  Function doesn't give the option for using a user-defined function.  On-entry might do it, but I don;t understand how that contraption works.  Maybe someone can give me a shove in the right direction,

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Please, provide and image of your spreadsheet and additional information in your question explaining your request in greater detail.

Comment: A link to my spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m1AZbIy7NU62YYKBKNQeQ6JwZICoiggo6DU9C27Wwn4/edit?usp=sharing"test" is above..  I want to know how to link the sorted list created in the above program for entry into C36-C67.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drop down in a cell with values from another range in another sheet in the same spreadsheet.

I am giving a code which I use.

The drop down in created in Column R

```
    allottedsheet.appendRow([planvalues[0][0], '=VLOOKUP($A'+(allottedlastrow+1)+',PLAN!$A:B,2,0)', '=VLOOKUP($A'+(allottedlastrow+1)+',PLAN!$A:C,3,0)', "Full Set"     , '=VLOOKUP(A'+(allottedlastrow+j)+',PLAN!A:E,5,0)',  '=VLOOKUP(A'+(allottedlastrow+j)+',PLAN!A:F,6,0)' ,'=VLOOKUP(A'+(allottedlastrow+j)+',PLAN!A:G,7,0)' ,"", 1         ,'=I'+(allottedlastrow+j)+'*E'+ (allottedlastrow+j),'',       wt,      fablab,'=J'+(allottedlastrow+j)+'*M'+(allottedlastrow+j),"",        "",       "",   '=VLOOKUP($A'+(allottedlastrow+1)+',PLAN!$A:K,11,0)' ,"",  color,     "",     "", "",     "",    planvalues[0][3], "",                 "",         "",      "",  planvalues[0][45]  ] )  ;
    var cell = allottedsheet.getRange('R'+(allottedlastrow+1));
    var range = contractorssheet.getRange('A2:A32');
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

The "contractor" sheet A2:A32 has the valid values. It has some empty values at the bottom. If a new contractor is the added, allow the user to add it at the bottom of the range.

Empty values do not display in drop down